# getting started with LESS

Tags: css, netbeans, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm very new to web design...okay, now that that's out of the way, where do I declare variables in the LESS/CSS framework?

I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.0.1
I'm also using Bootstrap 2.0 (not sure if this matters).
I downloaded the latest version of LESS from lesscss.org but it only downloads the minified version.

Here are my links and script tags in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/realcardio.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/less-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Can't wait to start assigning values to variables but I'm just not sure what file to do this in?

Thanks all!

Comment: Before you dive into less, I would start by getting a decent foundation in plain old css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it in your less file!

`sample.less`

```
@font_color: #666;
@font_size: 15px;

body {
    color: @font_color;
    font_size: @font_size;
}
```

Then you include this `.less` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="sample.less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Before you include the `less.js` file.

FYI, I find it's actually a much better model to hook up something so that every time you save your `.less` file in your editor, it compiles it using the node `lessc` compiler into a `.css` file and you just include that `.css` file in your page.

This way I don't have to run a convert before we do a deploy at work.

Comment: As the commenters above stated though, if you don't know CSS you're going to have a hard time with LESS since, well, LESS *IS* CSS.  It just provides some time-saving functionality, but you're still typing in pure CSS for the most part...

Comment: Thanks tkone. I got it working. With NetBeans you have to stop/start the project before seeing changes. A simple refresh of the browser won't do. I'll look into the compiler option you mentioned. I work in a Windows environment. Thanks again...

Comment: You want to accept the answer then? Node and therefor less for node both run under windows.